# Emacs function to load a site-start.d directory on Mac?

Tags: macos, emacs, elisp

Other systems such as Debian have code to load individual files inside `/etc/emacs/site-start.d` at startup. Now after install Magit using Homebrew there are files in `/usr/local/etc/emacs/site-start.d` that should be loaded at Emacs startup. Does stock Emacs have a function to do this, or must the functionality be ported from `debian-startup.el`?

If you don't know exactly what is being talked about here, please don't suggest arbitrary Elisp snippets to load files from a directory. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

/etc/emacs/site-start.d is a Debian addition to the load-path and startup process.  I'm not sure whether it is self-contained in debian-startup.el, but /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/site-start.el would be the standard location where something similar could be done (by using an arbitrary snippet to load files from a directory).